# Extjs grid with rowbody buttons handler

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a gridpanel in extjs 4.2.1 on which I am using the ftype rowbody to add additional elements to each row. In this case I am adding a row of buttons (tags) to each row.

```
features: [{
            ftype: 'rowbody',
            getAdditionalData: function(data, idx, record, orig) {
                var headerCt = this.view.headerCt
                var colspan  = headerCt.getColumnCount()
                var rowData = ''
                record.data.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
                    rowData += '<button class="tagDiv">' + tag.name + '</button>'
                })

                // Usually you would style the my-body-class in CSS file
                return {
                    rowBody: rowData,
                    rowBodyCls: 'tagRow',
                    rowBodyColspan: colspan
                }
            }
        }, {
            ftype: 'rowwrap'
        }],
```

So the tags are showing properly in the row, however I would like a to add listeners (click handlers) to those individual tags. Is this possible using rowbody or should I be adding these tags using some other method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add click handlers using some global scope.
My suggestion is to define a static handler for your grid class:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'orderlinesgrid',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.feature.RowBody'
    ],

    statics: {
        onTagClick: function(btn, tag) {
            // Click handler code...
        }
    }

    features: [{
        ftype: 'rowbody',
        getAdditionalData: function(data, idx, record, orig) {
            var headerCt = this.view.headerCt
            var colspan  = headerCt.getColumnCount()
            var rowData = ''
            record.data.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
                rowData += '<button class="tagDiv" onclick="MyApp.view.MyGrid.onTagClick(this,\'' + tag.name + '\')">' + tag.name + '</button>'
            })

            // Usually you would style the my-body-class in CSS file
            return {
                rowBody: rowData,
                rowBodyCls: 'tagRow',
                rowBodyColspan: colspan
            }
        }
    }, {
        ftype: 'rowwrap'
    }],
```